# Gitlab CI Runner; Which runner in the log is the actual runner, or what is each value?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to understand the Gitlab CI output and not finding documentation that clarifies. Each job runs one of two ways:

- On a shared runner that all can use.
- On a tagged runner with added credentials.

The former has log output like:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.8.2 (4d1ca121)
  on foo-common-shared-runner M7r-HDke, system ID: s_5f7784e6ad87
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
...
Running on runner-m7r-hdke-project-3141-concurrent-0 via runner-m7r-hdke-foo-common-shared-1678341790-609f9047...
```

And the latter like:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.8.2 (4d1ca121)
  on bar-default-runner gw8BqwwN, system ID: s_5f7784e6ad87
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
...
Running on runner-gw8bqwwn-project-3141-concurrent-0 via runner-gw8bqwwn-bar-default-1678373458-c5bbd8d4...
```

I'm trying to understand what I'm seeing here. I'm not sure what before and after the "via". I'm just not sure if we're spinning up instances of the same thing multiple times. If the part after the "via" is a separate instance, we are creating many more instances than seems necessary.

My questions are, what is each value:

- `4d1ca121`
- `foo-common-shared-runner M7r-HDke`
- `system ID: s_5f7784e6ad87`
- `runner-m7r-hdke-project-3141-concurrent-0`
- `runner-m7r-hdke-foo-common-shared-1678341790-609f9047`
- `bar-default-runner gw8BqwwN`
- `runner-gw8bqwwn-project-3141-concurrent-0`
- `runner-gw8bqwwn-bar-default-1678373458-c5bbd8d4`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a breakdown of the different values you are seeing:

1. "4d1ca121" - This is the version of GitLab Runner that is being used.
2. "foo-common-shared-runner M7r-HDke" - This is the name of the runner being used. It is possible to have multiple runners with different names.
3. "system ID: s_5f7784e6ad87" - This is a unique identifier for the runner's host system. It can be useful for troubleshooting issues with the runner.
4. "runner-m7r-hdke-project-3141-concurrent-0" - This is the name of the specific instance of the runner that is being used for the current job. The "project-3141" portion refers to the ID of the GitLab project that the pipeline is running for. The "concurrent-0" portion refers to the index of the current job in the pipeline.
5. "runner-m7r-hdke-foo-common-shared-1678341790-609f9047" - This is the full name of the runner instance that is executing the current job. It includes the name of the runner ("foo-common-shared-runner"), the unique ID of the runner instance ("M7r-HDke"), and a timestamp that indicates when the runner instance was started.
6. "bar-default-runner gw8BqwwN" - This is the name of a tagged runner that has been set up to run jobs with specific requirements, such as additional credentials.
7. "runner-gw8bqwwn-project-3141-concurrent-0" - This is the name of the specific instance of the tagged runner that is being used for the current job.
8. "runner-gw8bqwwn-bar-default-1678373458-c5bbd8d4" - This is the full name of the tagged runner instance that is executing the current job. It includes the name of the runner ("bar-default-runner"), the unique ID of the runner instance ("gw8BqwwN"), and a timestamp that indicates when the runner instance was started

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be exactly what I'm after, but I'm unable to understand the difference between "the name of the specific instance of the tagged runner" and "the full name of the tagged runner instance". Can you help clarify?